# Weird problem with a site layout on IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, draw

I have a website which draws white (empty) content/text on IE 7. However, as soon as I mouse over links, they will appear, or if I open up an about box and move it above the content, the content will then be drawn. Does anyone have any ideas what this is about? I can't supply source as this is private. the site works across all web browsers except for IE 7. IE 6 is untested.

Edit: it seems I was too unclear. I have code like this:

```
<p>text</p>
```

Which displays as black text against white background. This is how I want it to be, however, on IE 7, it will not render anything at all, unless I move IE 7 built-in windows above the text. Also, on some pages the part of the letters are invisible. For example, one P character did not have the left part of it and looked like a C in horizontal reverse.

Edit 2: Here is a screenshot of IE: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/3415/25633026.png

And this is all other browsers: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/1592/all.png

There should be text on the middle, but I see nothing. The code **is** valid. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.panssariprikaati.fi%2Ffi%2Ftiedotteet%2F2&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Not a lot I can do (personally) without seeing any evidence of this, does your code validate?

Comment: How are you doing it? White text on white background? display:none? And why are you trying to have content which isn't displayed to the user in the first place? This is considered black-hat SEO - pretty weak black-hat SEO it has to be said, but the search engines will not be kind to your site nonetheless.

Comment: I updated my question. It seems I was a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar in the past, but it seem to be resolved by ensuring the para's container had an explicit width/height.

A quick look through your CSS also shows that the container that is having problems has padding-left: 200px, are you using this to position the div?

Update: This is the link that I used to fix my problem, it was a 'layout' problem but fixed as described - http://haslayout.net/css/Disappearing-Content-Bug

Comment: Yes it positions the div properly.